# How can I keep the Java Virtual Machine running and send requests

Tags: python, server, jvm

I'm a beginner in Java, and I want to send planning requests to a [planner](https://github.com/pellierd/pddl4j/blob/devel/src/main/java/fr/uga/pddl4j/planners/htn/stn/TFD.java).

The problem is that the execution time is huge due to the fact that I'm launching the `JVM` at each time!

Can you please tell me how to keep the `JVM` running as a server and send requests instead of launching the `JVM` each time to reduce the execution time? thanks in advance.

I'm using `python` to call the `JVM` like this:

```py
    def solver( 
        libraryPath='PDDL/pddl4j-devel/build/libs/pddl4j-3.8.3.jar',
        planner = 'fr.uga.pddl4j.planners.htn.stn.tfd.TFDPlanner',
        Memory = ['-Xms12288m' ,'-Xmx12288m'],
        domainPath  = 'new_domain.pddl',
        problemPath = 'problem_main.pddl',
        save=False
        ):
        """
        Function: solver, to run the solver and get a plan if there is one.
        ---
        Parameters:
        @param: planner, string, planner name.
        @param: libraryPath, string, the path to the java library(extension included)
        @param: Memory, list of two ['-Xms size m', -Xmx size m'].
        @param: domainPath, string, the path to the domain, (extension included).
        @param: problemPath, string, the path to the problem, (extension included).
        @param: save, boolean, to save the plan as log file.
        ---
        @return: None.
        """
        cmd = ['java', '-javaagent:'+libraryPath, '-server' , Memory[0] , Memory[1], planner, '-d', self.path+domainPath, '-p', self.path+problemPath]
        result = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: There isn't any such mode built in. The "-server" parameter just selects a JIT compiler which is suitable for long running server-side processes, although the parameter is obsolete these days. You'll need to implement your own server by listening on a socket.

Comment: Did you measure the execution time? How long it typically is? Is the significant portion really the startup time of the java process or does the actual running time of the planner algorithm dominate the total execution time?

Comment: @JurajMartinka The total execution time is around 0.596 sec divided into encoding and search times, encoding time is around 0.593, so if the encoding is done once, the search will not take long time.

Comment: @Bilal and what is the total time including the startup of the java subprocess?

Comment: @boneill "*You'll need to implement your own server by listening on a socket.*", is there any show case example / tutorial that can you please recommend about this approach. thank in advance.

Comment: @JurajMartinka sorry for late reply, `Total time=1.0790348052978516`, `Encoding time = 0.585s`, `Searching time = 0.003s`, `Total Planning time  =: 0.588s`, this indicates that the "*startup of the java subprocess*" is about `0.4s` which is not acceptable at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The startup time overhead is less than 50%. I understand that it's not ideal but unless you optimize your planner quite a bit I wouldn't be worried that much. ]

Building a long-running java server app is another option as already mentioned. There are numerous frameworks for that such as Spring.

For you, that's likely an overkill so you can check some tutorials about building "simple http server", e.g.

- https://dzone.com/articles/simple-http-server-in-java
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNUdLeGfShU&list=PLAuGQNR28pW56GigraPdiI0oKwcs8gglW

Or go even lower level with sockets: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html